# React-Native splash screen scaled to all screens(iphone, Ipad, Tablet ...)

Tags: react-native, splash-screen, launch-screen, react-native-splash-screen

I am developing an application with React Native, and I want to add a splash screen to it. I want the added splash screen to look good on various devices, including iPhone 15 Pro Max, iPad Pro 11 inch, Android devices/tablets...

My application works in landscape mode, so the splash screen is also landscape.

What packages can I use for this purpose?

I was using 'react-native-splash-screen,' but it doesn't provide resizing/scaling based on different devices. I heard that creating different folders for Android might solve this issue (I attached a photo below). If you have information about that, please share.

The main issue is on the XCode side for iOS devices. Do you have any package names or articles I can read regarding this for iOS?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try `react-native-bootsplash` package. Maybe it can solve your issue. If that doesn't work, you'll need to get your hands on the native files (Android & Ios).